# Ошибка 1042 "Can't get hostname for your address" при установке MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows

Пытался установить последнюю официальную версию MySQl на 64-битную Windows. Всё оставлял по умолчанию. Когда настройка доходит до "Starting server", просто ломается, показывая ошибку 1042 " Can't get hostname for your address".

При этом, когда я снова захожу в установщик и пытаюсь реконфигурировать MySQL Server, то он не принимает пароль, что я вводил. Раньше спокойно ставил себе MySQL, не могу понять, что так изменилось, что появился баг. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как от него избавиться.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверить сетевые настройки mysql-сервера в my.cfg

И на всякий случай можешь прописать имя своего хоста и соответствующий ему ip-адресс в файл

```
/etc/hosts
```

это в unix-like

а в windows

```
%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

записи там имеют следующий вид:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Если твой сервер биндит порт не localhost-а (согласно настройкам mysql), то пропиши то имя которое ему задал как-то так

```
192.168.1.1 myhostname
```